# How model binding works when posting a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have this View model:

```
public class CalendarViewModel
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public List<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller post would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCalendar(CalendarViewModel model)
```

I'm trying something like:

```
foreach(Week s in @Model.Weeks)
{
         <div class="control-group">
               <label>Week @s.WeekIndex</label>
               <div class="controls">
                     @Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Weeks.Description)
               </div>
         </div>
}
```

However, It obviously doesn't work like this. The view is strongly typed to this model. How should the View pass the data to the controller using lambda expressions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an int array to MVC Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575246/passing-an-int-array-to-mvc-controller)

Comment: Take a look at the answer in the link above to see how model binding with collections works.

Comment: Your need to use a `for` loop so the controls are correctly named with indexers `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Weeks.Count; 1++) { @Html.TextboxFor(m => m[i].Description) ...` Review the html generated before and after.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, `@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Weeks[i].Description)` was what I was looking for!